# wordpress Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file

Tags: wordpress

i just moved wordpress from hosting server to my local machine. but got an error like this

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /opt/lampp/htdocs/wp/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php on line 1190
```

How to solved

Answer (score 2):

It means that the file is incomplete/broken. You did not move the full file but just part of it. You can fix it by either downloading the file from hosting server again (just that one) or by downloading wordpress from wordpress.org and copy that file.

Answer (score 0):

Pls check the file：class-wp-list-table.php on line 1190，
Probably you have modified it, So just delete what you added in Line 1190, then try again!